# Creating new installation for testnig hardware

Tags: system-installation, ssd

My desktop is really running slow.

I am going to run a test to find out if my hardware is the problem, or if there's just too much 'stuff' running on my existing LTS 22.xx.xx SSD system disk.

I bought a new SSD drive, and I'm going to install the latest LTS 22.xx.xx on it, and unplug the existing SSD with the existing 22.xx.xx LTS version on it.  I have two computers sitting next to it, so I don't have to create anything on the node I'm updating.  I intend to install the software that I'm using daily onto this new SSD, but none of the other programs that are on my old system SSD, so I can have as clean a machine as possible for testing.

If it is fast enough, then I intend to use this minimal-software node for the single application, and use the other node (much more powerful) for any other applications.

Are there any files, from the existing SSD node that would make life easier for me to copy?  I'm thinking about LAN configuration files, etc.

I don't want to clone or copy the existing SSD, because then I would have all the other 'stuff' and wouldn't be able to conduct a clean-slate test.

Thanks!

My home data is on another drive, so I'll mount that to the /home directory.

I'll create my user with the same user info from /etc/passwd file.

However, there will be some LAN stuff, machine name, etc that

Comment: A stock install of Ubuntu includes diagnostic tools to determine why your system seems slow.

Comment: Do you have any you've used that you can recommend?

Comment: A search for Ubuntu diagnostic tools via Google turns up some commands, but I don't know enough to interpret there output.  For instance, toph gives me a list of things that are consuming cpu resources, but I don't know if I actually need them for my system.  So I'm currently of the opinion that it would be simpler and faster just to try a fresh install and see how it performs.

Comment: Start with plain old `top` to see if you have a CPU constraint, and `free -h` to see if you have a memory constraint. On a desktop system, use your System Monitor application. All of those are included with a stock install of Ubuntu. reviewing your logs can also help troubleshooting. A "slow" system can also be more clearly defined in your question: Maybe it's slow at certain times during use, but acceptably fast at other times. Focus on details of those times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your assistance.  As I mentioned in the opening question, I didn't want to have to deal with researching what might be causing the slowdown, because it exceeds my knowledge of Linux, and was just looking for what directories/files I might need to copy or link into a new instance.

I did create a new instance of Ubuntu 23 LTS, on a new SSD, then mounted my /home user account, and ran some tests.

I then installed the couple of software applications that I was most interesting in running on this new instances.

This worked, giving me very fast results on my existing hardware.

I'm happy!

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!